# how to return array for mysql_query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, arrays

```
  // make empty array
  $sqlArray=array();
  $jsonArray=array();


  // START NEED FAST WORKING ALTERNATİVES -----------------------------------------------------
  // first 20 vistors
  $query = "SELECT user_id FROM vistors LIMIT 20"; 
  $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ($query);

  // make vistors user query array
  while ($vstr_line = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($sqlArray, $vstr_line['user_id']);
  }

  // implode vistors user array
  $sqlArray_impl = implode("', '", $sqlArray);
 // END NEED FAST WORKING ALTERNATİVES -----------------------------------------------------


  // Get vistors information
  $query = "SELECT id, username, picture FROM users WHERE id IN ('$sqlArray_impl')"; 
  $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die($query);


  while ($usr_line = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
    array_push($jsonArray, $usr_line['id'].' - '.$usr_line['username'].' - '.$usr_line['picture']);
  }


  print_r($sqlArray);

  echo '<br><br>';

  print_r($jsonArray);
```

see this my functions..
i need a replacement for fast working alternatives..

function within the range specified above, to me, running faster than the alternative.
the query will return back array ?

thx for all helpers !

Comment: That sort of behavior is perfectly fine (IMO, I hope I'm not ignorant.) It shouldn't be slow unless your query time is bad. Have you profiled it? Could you give us some numbers that show why you need it faster?

Comment: why not nest the query? select id,username... from ysers where id in(select user_id from visitors limit 20)

Comment: Do you have any certain reason to ask for "fast alternatives"? Do you have any problem at the moment with the code? NOT with query, but with present code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Can you use a JOIN or SUB SELECT to reduce the query count from 2 to 1? Might not give much of a boost but worth a shot and a cleaner implementation.
2. Where is the bottleneck? Most likely the db and not the php code.
3. Are the tables/columns properly indexed? Run EXPLAIN on both queries.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to include first query as subquery eliminating one turn to the DB and a lot of code:

```
  // Get vistors information
  $query = "SELECT id, username, picture FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM vistors LIMIT 20)"; 
  $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die($query);
```

Unless there is more reason to have the first one seperate, but that is not visible in your code example.

Comment: SELECT id, username, picture FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM vistors LIMIT 20) -> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 20)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

If you use PDO (recommended anyway...), you can return the result array all at once using [`fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

For your second query, you can use [string concatenation in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to directly return the result you want.